# Removing Trojan Virus using Avast

Tags: trojan, avast

I dont have any antivirus on my PC because its only for gaming use only. I dont know where did i get these trojan virus, it makes my PC slow and my it eats my HD and also makes my internet slow. I tried to remove it using some software but still it exist.

if i install avast with an existing Trojan after it is installed and scan the computer, can avast delete it?

I havent tried Avast. Just asking. Thanks

Comment: Without specifying which trojan, it's hard to tell. Please give more details about what you find.

Comment: I dont know what kind of trojan it is, but it consumes my hard disk from 30 GB now its 89GB but i only have 2 games with 12GB

Comment: You don't state how you know (think) you have a virus, and you haven't tried an AV yet... because??

Comment: Because its only for gaming and some anti virus is blocking these games such as Dragon Nest thats why i didnt install any anti virus. Also im using my PC for about 2 hrs a day.

Comment: Try the suggestions linked to in the above post. Ideally reinstall your OS, because once infected you may always have problems. And please install anti-virus software.

Comment: okay thanks. I'll go to the nearest computer repair shop right now.

Answer (score 0):

Avast! is quite good, Extremely light and BUT It doesn't have a good reputation for some reason. Avast! may lack at detecting "all" the viruses from your system, and it may leave some behind undetected. It works great and it does NOT slow down computers but It can be annoying due to the repeated update boxes and notifications.

Have you ever tried using [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/pro/)?

Malwarebytes Anti-Malware (MBAM) is an on-demand scanner which can be used to find and remove trojans, along with other malware such as viruses, worms, rootkits, diallers and spyware.

The program is intuitive and simple to use.

As there are daily updates, always ensure the software has been updated prior to scanning your PC. For those of a forgetful nature, you can set the program to warn about the database being outdated.

Comment: okay ill try that. sorry i dont have any idea on computers

Comment: No worries it is really easy to use and cleans everything. "Squeaky clean" clean. :)